# Do I need to add "inherited" line into record constructors?

Tags: delphi, constructor, record

Modern Delphi allows constructors for records. I have the following code:

```
{ TKMRect }
constructor TKMRect.Create(aPoint: TKMPoint);
begin
  inherited; // <<- Do I need to add this line ?

  Left := aPoint.X;
  Top := aPoint.Y;
  Right := aPoint.X;
  Bottom := aPoint.Y;
end;
```

My question is - do I need to add `inherited` line in my records constructors? And why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you don't need to do this because records don't support inheritance and so `inherited` is a no-op in this context.

FWIW I regard record constructors as an anti pattern. It makes it hard for the reader at the call site to distinguish between value type and reference type. I personally use static class functions named `New` that return a new value for this purpose. You can argue over whether a different name is better, but it doesn't matter so long is it isn't `Create`.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks for clarification!